# Option to change date format of column in Tableau not available

Tags: tableau-api

I have a Tableau worksheet where one of the fields is a date field with format MDY(e.g August 30, 2020). I am trying to change its format to MM/DD/YYYY( e.g. 08/30/2020)

According to the documentation, I should be able to change the format by right clicking the date field in the view section and selecting the format option.

However, when I do the above, I only see 'Null' in the format option (See screenshot below)
[screenshot of format options for the date field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGnI1.jpg)
I am not sure why the option would be unavailable here, can someone help me out here please?

Comment: Does Tableau think your date is a date?

Answer (score 0):

Your date is actually a date part. Change to the Day per below then set to discrete.

[image]

[image]

Now format as desired.

[image]